# Unnamed folder in '/' appears as (permission denied) in xdiskusage, but not in ls -a

Tags: linux, file-permissions, hidden-file

Somewhat scarce in space in my '/' partition, I ran `xdiskusage`, and found a folder marked (permission-denied), about 2 GB in size. It doesn't have a name (unless the name is also denied). I've never seen this before (I don't run xdiskusage frequently), and I can't see it using `ls -a`.

I don't have a swap file configured, and I'm confused what this file could be.

Any suggestions?

(This isn't just a 'permissions' issue as most items I found on the subject seem to imply. I can't change permissions as the file/folder doesn't even have a name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real folder, it's the *sum* of all folders in any location that `xdiskusage` that was not able to look inside due to permission issues.

(Specifically, as the manual page says, it's the difference between what the filesystem reports as "used" via `df`, and what total file size xdiskusage itself could see.)

Run `find / -xdev > /dev/null` to see a list of all such folders.

Use `sudo ncdu -x /` to get an overview of disk usage as root.

Comment: `find / -xdev > /dev/null` doesn't produce anything. I don't have `ncdu` installed, so I ran `du` instead, but the output is huge. Will install `ncdu`. Thanks.

Comment: Ok... Ran `ncdu` (and read the `man xdiskusage` - ashamed I didn't think of that first). The manual seems to imply this space could be due to programs which have not released it yet. Any way to identify those programs?

Comment: Tools like `lsfd` or `lsof` will list such files as "(deleted)"; deleted files are released when the last process closes them. (Ignore the ones named "memfd:something".)